# error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Tags: sql

does any body knows why when I run this query its is error **"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int."**<\font>

Comment: Because comma `,` is not a valid number/integer?

Comment: any idea how to fix this  ?

Comment: `SELECT TRY_PARSE(col_name AS INT) FROM tab_name`. Use `TRY_PARSE`(SQL Server 2012+).

Comment: An idea how to fix it? There is nothing to fix. You are saying: "My string contains an integer number" and the DBMS tells you: "No, it contains a comma". So don't try to treat the comma like an integer. It isn't an integer.

Comment: mmm make sense  silly of me I forgot those are int

Comment: I don't see any SQL in your request. Where is your query? I also don't see any DBMS tagged. Which DBMS are you using? The concatenation operator in standard SQL is `||`. The only DBMS I know of using `+` for concatenation instead is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like error from ms sql server. In tsql you can use [cast and convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
You should read this: [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio doesn't get OS regional Setting](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/458416/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-doesnt-get-os-regional-setting)